# In MVC project why jQuery print() function failed to load css

Tags: jquery, css, .net, asp.net-mvc

In MVC project need to print a partial view. For the print used the following jQuery syntax, it's work fine problem it's failed to load the CSS, bootstrap and inline.

How to enable CSS for the jQuery Print function?

[image]

**Jquery print function**

```
<script>

    $("document").ready(function (e) {


        $('body').on("click", "#btnPrint", function (e) {

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {},
                url: '/Home/QuickReportViewPDF',

                success: function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=900');
                    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Medical Hub</title>');
                    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                    printWindow.document.write(response);
                    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                    printWindow.document.close();
                    printWindow.print();
                },
                error: function (data) {


                }
            });
        });

    });


</script>
```

**Home Controller**

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult QuickReportViewPDF()
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

**Index.chhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <button id="btnPrint" class="btn btn-primary">Print Report</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="first" class="redscore col-md-4" data-high="400" data-low="300" data-score="399" style="background-color: red;min-height: 20px; ">
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="second" class="yelowscore col-md-4" data-high="299" data-low="200" data-score="399" style="background-color: yellow;min-height: 20px;">
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="third" class="greenscore col-md-4" data-high="199" data-low="0" data-score="399" style="background-color: green;min-height: 20px; ">
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        $("document").ready(function (e) {


            $('body').on("click", "#btnPrint", function (e) {

                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {},
                    url: '/Home/QuickReportViewPDF',

                    success: function (response) {
                        debugger;
                        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=900');
                        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Medical Hub</title>');
                        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                        printWindow.document.write(response);
                        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                        printWindow.document.close();
                        printWindow.print();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {


                    }
                });
            });

        });


    </script>

<style>
    #wrapper {
        display: flex;
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    }

    #first {
        background-color: red !important;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #second {
        background-color: yellow !important;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #third {
        background-color: green !important;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you open that URL directly?

Comment: You're injecting content, which already has a full html/head/body defined, in to a HTML string which itself has a html/head/body defined. Remove one of those structures.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan, create another view without the head/body tags but get the same result.

Comment: @shamim Make sure (in the print dialog) the following option is checked: `More settings > Options > Background graphics`.

Comment: @jom, change on configuration enables background image but not enable the CSS.